# Maildrop on iOS stopped working after iOS 8

Tags: iphone, ios, video

It used to work fine under iOS 8. I do not remember if the problems started with iOS 9.0 or after subsequent updates.

I am not able to send (movie) files over 25MB from iPhone 6s, iOS 9.3.2, from MyName@iCloud.com.  As expected, it asks me if I want to send the file directly or via Maildrop. If choose Maildrop. It gets stuck in outbox, saying

> Cannot send mail
>   The connection to the outgoing server p38-smtp.mail.me.com failed
>   Additional outgoing servers in mail settings...

I get a similar message when attempting to send from other email accounts: yahoo mail, gmail, my ISP mail (IMAP).

All these attempts from the default Mail app on iOS.

If I choose "send directly" it attempts to do it without compressing the movie on-the-fly (like in the past). Then I am at the mercy of the mail servers. It can go thru or it can get stuck. I do not know if in the past iOS was compressing the video on-the-fly in response to the outgoing server not being able to send it or iOS had its own threshold.

Q1: How do I fix Maildrop?
There are no other servers to choose from in mail settings, so the error message is not helpful.

This does not seem to be an iCloud problem, Maildrop works fine from my Mac OSX (Yosemite).

Q2: Can someone confirm that the old compress-on-the-fly functionality is really gone? 
This would be a good workaround to sending movies when Maildrop does not work. (I cannot even compress them separately, in iMovie. It seems that iMovie is crippled, too.)